# Save file to remote server MVC5

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to upload a file to a remote server. I have this MVC5 site on local server (machine A) and the file should go to another server (machine B).

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Gender,AutoLogin,Password,ScreenName,NotificationsOn,ThumbnailURL")] User user, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files[0];
        if (photo != null)
        {
            //do some stuff with the file, like limit size and extensions

            //smp = localhost folder (machine A) and I need the remote folder(machine B). 
            //How do I do this? If I need FTP, how to connect?
            string smp = Server.MapPath("~/UserContent/");
            photo.SaveAs(smp" + photo.FileName);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

Comment: You have various ways of transferring files between machines. Which approach are you going to be using? FTP, FTPS, SFTP, HTTP, File Sharing, ...

Comment: I would use the least complex one. Can you tell me which one is it and how to use it? Thanks

Comment: It really depends on your architecture. You can create a shared folder between the 2 machines and just save your files in the shared folder.